# Stored procedure or function expects parameter which wasn't supplied

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a stored procedure in a `SqlCommand` in C#.

This is the code in C#:

```
string s = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ToString();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(s);

conn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Signup1", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

string password = TextBox2.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", email));

SqlParameter pass = cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
pass.Value = password;

SqlParameter usertype = cmd.Parameters.Add("@usrtype", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
usertype.Value =usertype.Value;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
```

This is the stored procedure:

```
Create Proc Signup1
    @email varchar(20),
    @password Varchar(24),
    @usrtype Varchar(30)
as
    Insert into Members(email, password)
    Values(@email, @password)

    if @usrtype = 'Normal User'
    begin
        Insert into Normal_Users(email)
        Values(@email)
    end
    else if @usrtype = 'Development Team'
    begin
        Insert into Development_Eeams(email)
        Values(@email)
    end
    else if @usrtype = 'Verified Reviewer'
    begin
        Insert into Verified_reviewers(email)
        Values(@email)
    end
    else
        raiserror('Invalid type',16,1)
```

When I execute the command I get this error

> Procedure or function 'Signup1' expects parameter '@password', which was not supplied.

Though I did gave the procedure the value of the parameter, what is the solution? Thanks

Comment: Why do you define them as different sizes when you add them in the C# than they are in the stored procedure? And since other people will say it, you are opening yourself to issues storing plain text passwords.

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", email));` perhaps this is the problem.. where are you defining email..?

Comment: you need to really debug your code as well as understand how you are defining things you are declaring things in code larger than the data size that the stored procedure is expecting..

Comment: @RonBeyer , I changed the size to be equal to that in the procedure but I still have the same error ?! ,about the password I just want to handle the user's input in the database .Later I will have to change it .

Answer (score 0):

```
string email = //where are you getting the email address
string password = TextBox2.Text;
string s = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ToString();
using (SqlConnection connStr new SqlConnection(s);
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Signup1", connStr))
{
    c.Open();
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = email });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = password });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@usrtype", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = userType }); //Where are you assigning userType
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

if the top example is to complicated then you can use the `Parameters.AddWithValue` Function and let the DB Server handle resolving the datatype  for example

```
string email = //where are you getting the email address
string password = TextBox2.Text;
string s = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ToString();
using (SqlConnection connStr new SqlConnection(s);
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Signup1", connStr))
{
    c.Open();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue"@password", password);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrtype", userType); //Where are you assigning userType
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```